# Updating a form in the UI-tier from a class in the Logic-tier?

Tags: c#, architecture

I'm new to using 3-tier architecture. I have a form with a dataGridView and I have a Logic class which has a timer. The form is running an instance of the logic class. The timer procs every 10 seconds. I'm being told I should be using events, but I don't see how exactly this works. Right now, the timer runs, and every ten seconds it runs the method onUpdated. Here's the timer from the logic class:

```
    public void timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t.Interval = 1000;
        t.Enabled = true;
        if (counter >= 10)
        {
            counter = 0;
            OnUpdated();
        }
        else
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

Then it runs OnUpdated:

```
    protected void OnUpdated()
    {
        if (Updated != null) Updated();
    }
```

I want the logic layer to run this method in the form. This method fetches the current tables in a database.

```
    private void dataGridViewUpdate()
    {
        dsCitizen.Clear();
        dsTemp.Clear();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
        dsCitizen = lInst.getDataSetCitizen();
        dsTemp = lInst.getDataSetTemporary();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dsCitizen.Tables[0];
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dsTemp.Tables[0];
    }
```

I'm sure I'm supposed to be running this somewhere

```
lInst.Updated += Update; //lInst is an instance of my logic class in the form
```

But I don't know where.
If you have some other solution than using events, be my guest!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just ensure that you are using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` when you are referencing @AbZy's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Timer `Tick` is itself an event, so you don't need to handle another event. You could just call the method `dataGridViewUpdate` from within `timerTick` event. set `t.Interval = 10000` (thats 10 seconds) outside the event and you don't need to use that counter variable.

```
    private Timer t ;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t  = new Timer();
        t.Interval = 10000;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(timerTick);
        t.Start();

    }

    public void timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridViewUpdate();      
    }

    private void dataGridViewUpdate()
    {
        dsCitizen.Clear();
        dsTemp.Clear();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView2.DataSource = null;
        dsCitizen = lInst.getDataSetCitizen();
        dsTemp = lInst.getDataSetTemporary();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dsCitizen.Tables[0];
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dsTemp.Tables[0];
    }
```